# How do I filter all items that occur once into one list and all items that occur multiple times into a different one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I'm currently working on a project but I'm stuck with  removing all the duplicates.

I need to remove all the duplicate names  and put into a separate file

This is an example of what Im trying to achieve:
So I have an array of numbers (1,2,2,3,3,4,5) and I would like to remove  all of the duplicates from the array to result in (1,4,5).

Comment: Do you really want to remove or reduce them? For example: [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5] returns, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: I  want to remove them into a file on its own. I want it to return [1,4,5] in 1 file and [2,2,3,3] into another file.@AksJacoves

Comment: Will the array always be sorted?

Comment: no , but that might be something to consider@Thomas

Answer (score 1):

For loop the array and place each value into a hash map that tracks the number of times that number is recorded. Then loop through your hash map and create a new array with only the values that have a record of 1.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5];

function removeDuplicates(arr) {

    var hashMap = {};
    for(let i of arr) {
        if(hashMap[i]){
            hashMap[i] += 1
        } else {
            hashMap[i] = 1
        }
    }

    var newArray = [];
    for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(hashMap)){
        if(value === 1) {
            newArray.push(parseInt(key));
        } else {
            // If you want to do something with values recorded more
            // than once, you can do that here.
        }
    }

    return newArray;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using any external libraries - I am sure there are more concise ways to do it, but this should work:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5];

function removeDuplicates(array) {

  var existingValues = [];   // Holds all values that exist at least once
  var duplicates = [];       // Holds all values that are duplicates

  array.forEach(function(num) {
    if (existingValues.indexOf(num) === -1) {
      existingValues.push(num);
    } else {
      duplicates.push(num);
    }
  });

  // Filter out the values from existingValues that are in the duplicates array
  return existingValues.filter(function(i) {
    return duplicates.indexOf(i) === -1;
  });

}

console.log(removeDuplicates(numbers)); // [1,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Will the array always be sorted?
>
> no , but that might be something to consider @Thomas

OK, this would have allowed for something like this:

Just looking at the neighbors to determine wether a value is single or has multiple occurances.

```js
const array = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5];
const single = [];
const multiple = [];

for (let i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; ++i) {
  let value = array[i];
  const isDupe = i > 0 && value === array[i - 1]
    || i + 1 < length && value === array[i + 1];

  if (isDupe) {
    multiple.push(value);
  } else {
    single.push(value);
  }
}

console.log("singles", single);
console.log("multiple", multiple);
```

If the data ain't guaranteed to be sorted we need to do a count pass first the check which items are unique in that array and which ones are not. And in a secnd pass we can add them to the result arrays.

```js
const array = [3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
const single = [];
const multiple = [];
const count = {};

for (let i = 0; i<array.length; ++i) {
  let value = array[i];
  count[value] = (count[value] || 0) + 1;
}

for (let i = 0; i<array.length; ++i) {
  let value = array[i];
  if (count[value] > 1) {
    multiple.push(value);
  } else {
    single.push(value);
  }
}

console.log("singles", single);
console.log("multiple", multiple);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the input you gave:  [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]  and the fact you said you wanted two outputs: one with the unique values, [1,4,5], and one with duplicates [2,2,3,3].

The below function will give you two arrays as outputs, one with the unique values, and one with the duplicates.

```
const getUniqueAndDuplicates = (arr) =>{

    //use a JavaScript object as a map to count frequency
    const map={};
    for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(map[arr[i]]){map[arr[i]]++;}
        else{map[arr[i]]=1;}
    }

    const uniqueArray=[];
    const duplicateArray=[];



    for(let key in map){
        //get the frequency count
        let freq=map[key];

        if(freq===1){uniqueArray.push(key);}
        else{
            for(let i=0;i<freq;i++){
                duplicateArray.push(key);
            }
        }

    }

    return [uniqueArray,duplicateArray];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to remove duplication in array. Here's some samples.

#### Using Set()

> Set objects are collections of values. You can iterate through the
>   elements of a set in insertion order. A value in the Set may only
>   occur once

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

```js
const duplicated = [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,5];
const uniqSet = new Set(duplicated);
console.log([...uniqSet]) // Should be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

#### Using lodash uniq() method

Document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

const duplicated = [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,5];
const uniq = _.uniq(duplicated);
console.log(uniq) // Should be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

#### Scratch

```js
const duplicated = [1,2,3,2,3,4,3,5];
const uniq = [];

for (const e of duplicated) {
  if (!uniq.includes(e)) {
    uniq.push(e)
  }
}

console.log(uniq) // Should be [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: The title is misleading. OP actually want's to filter all items that occur once into one list and all items that occur multiple times into a different one.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry if it was misleading. But I wasn't sure of the right  wording hence my example. Thanks for your help. Updated  question